# calculate the number of months between two dates, iterate a function on each month

Tags: javascript

I'm needing to write a function that takes two dates (startDate, endDate) calculates the time between them in months or years (depending on an input). When the number of months or years is found, I need to iterate a loop that runs a very simple ajax call (I'm adding a record to Quickbase) for every month OR year between the start and end dates.

I've taken a couple of hacks at this but I'm running into trouble when I try to calculate months (due to the calendar dates (i.e. feb having 28 days etc)... I've calculated the time between the two dates in days, but I need months or years.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: None of the answers in the "original" post takes care of the 28th of february and so on, as the OP askes about..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just to start try

```
function Noofmonths(date1, date2) {
    var Nomonths;
    Nomonths= (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    Nomonths-= date1.getMonth() + 1;
    Nomonths+= date2.getMonth() +1; // we should add + 1 to get correct month number
    return Nomonths <= 0 ? 0 : Nomonths;
}
```

Comment: This worked great on getting the months. Another question though. What if the start and end date don't have the same day of the month? I.e. startDate == 10-26-2004 && endDate == 10-16-2006?  There is a remainder of days, and I'm lost as to what logic finds this.

Answer (score 1):

obtain date1 year and date2 year.
get the difference and multiply by 12.
obtain date1 month and date2 month.
get the difference.
add the differences together.

Comment: your answer is the description of my answer..!!

Comment: why down vote. is that not mathematically a solution? :(

Comment: sorry i posted too slow.

Comment: Somebody downvoted your answer and gone..!!

Comment: i don't care. moving on.